# Why does the data binding source need an explicit getter?

Tags: windows-phone-7, data-binding

If I don't add explicit accessors to a String property, then data binding doesn't work. Why is that?
Here is a simple example where a text box is hooked up to a String property.

MainPage.xaml:

```
<Grid Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Message} />
</Grid>
```

And the code behind:

```
public String Message;

public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Message = "Hello World";
    DataContext = this;
}
```

This does not work, the text box is empty.

However, add property accessors;

```
public String Message { get; set; };
```

And now it works.

I can't see this explained in [MSDN Data Binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278072%28VS.95%29.aspx). Can someone explain it? Don't properties have an implict set/get accessors? Even so, why can't data binding just access the property?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public String Message;
```

This is a field, not a property. Adding getters and setters creates an auto property. 
Only properties can be bound to.

Comment: @Slaks, @devdigital and @Matti_Virkkunen: you all have the same answer but it turns out are all not quite correct.. You all clarified for me the difference between a field and a property - I didn't realize that. And that led me to the correct answer: Bindings only works with properties **when a path is involved**, othwerwise it can directly access a field. Eg: Above is `DataContext = Message;` then `<TextBlock Text="{Binding}">` does work! So using a path needs accessors. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.source(v=vs.95).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

The `{ get; set; }` is what makes the compiler generate those implicit accessors. If you leave that out, you're not creating a property at all, but a simple field.

I'm not into XAML that much so I can't say for sure, but maybe it just doesn't support binding to plain fields.

Answer (score 2):

`public String Message;` is a field, not a property.
Databinding only works with properties.